# White Error Screen Appears when I try to update from form

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

I am getting a white error screen when I try to add an item via a form in python / django. I am trying to debug it but there is no information. Can somebody point me in the right direction?[image]

Models.py

```html
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.utils import timezone


# Create your models here.
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', default='Upload Picture')
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="profile")
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    county = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=7, null=True)
    biography = models.TextField(max_length=280,blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    dob = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True)
    facebook = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    twitter = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    instagram = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

class KidProfile(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='kids')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    dob = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, null=True, blank=True)
    needs = models.CharField(max_length=3, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__ (self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```html
from django.contrib import messages, auth
from accounts.forms import UserRegistrationForm, UserLoginForm, FullUserDetailsForm, KidDetailsForm
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse, get_object_or_404
from django.template.context_processors import csrf
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .models import KidProfile, UserProfile

@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login')
def profile(request):
    kids = KidProfile.objects.filter(parent=request.user)
    adults = UserProfile.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'profile.html', {'kids': kids}, {'adults': adults})

def update_profile(request):
    form=FullUserDetailsForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        request.user.first_name=form.cleaned_data['first_name']
        request.user.last_name=form.cleaned_data['last_name']
        request.user.email=form.cleaned_data['email']
        request.user.profile.address1=form.cleaned_data['address1']
        request.user.profile.address2=form.cleaned_data['address2']
        request.user.profile.postcode=form.cleaned_data['postcode']
        request.user.profile.phone=form.cleaned_data['phone']
        request.user.profile.dob=form.cleaned_data['dob']
        request.user.profile.gender=form.cleaned_data['gender']
        request.user.profile.facebook=form.cleaned_data['facebook']
        request.user.profile.twitter=form.cleaned_data['twitter']
        request.user.profile.instagram=form.cleaned_data['instagram']
        request.user.save()
        return redirect(reverse('profile'))
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Error")

def update_profile_kid(request, id):
    kid = get_object_or_404(KidProfile, pk=id)
    form=KidDetailsForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        kid.name=form.cleaned_data['name']
        kid.dob=form.cleaned_data['dob']
        kid.gender=form.cleaned_data['gender']
        kid.needs=form.cleaned_data['needs']
        kid.save()
        return redirect(reverse('profile'))
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Error")

def create_profile_kid(request):
    form=KidDetailsForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        kid=KidProfile()
        kid.name=form.cleaned_data['name']
        kid.dob=form.cleaned_data['dob']
        kid.gender=form.cleaned_data['gender']
        kid.needs=form.cleaned_data['needs']
        kid.parent=request.user
        kid.save()
        return redirect(reverse('profile'))
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Error")

def delete_profile_kid(request, id):
    kid = get_object_or_404(KidProfile, pk=id)
    kid.delete()
    return redirect(reverse('profile'))



def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserLoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = auth.authenticate(username=request.POST.get('username_or_email'),
                                     password=request.POST.get('password'))

            if user is not None:
                auth.login(request, user)
                messages.error(request, "You have successfully logged in")

                if request.GET and request.GET['next'] !='':
                    next = request.GET['next']
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(next)
                else:
                    return redirect(reverse('babysitters'))
            else:
                form.add_error(None, "Your username or password was not recognised")
    else:
        form = UserLoginForm()

    args = {'form': form, 'next': request.GET['next'] if request.GET and 'next' in request.GET else ''}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    return render(request, 'login.html', args)



def logout(request):
    auth.logout(request)
    messages.success(request, 'You have successfully logged out')
    return redirect(reverse('index'))


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            user = auth.authenticate(username=request.POST.get('username'),
                                     password=request.POST.get('password1'))

            if user:
                auth.login(request, user)
                messages.success(request, "You have successfully registered")
                return redirect(reverse('profile'))

            else:
                messages.error(request, "unable to log you in at this time!")

    else:
        form = UserRegistrationForm()

    args = {'form': form}

    return render(request, 'profile.html', args)
```

urls.py

```html
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import register, profile, logout, login, update_profile, update_profile_kid, create_profile_kid, delete_profile_kid

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^register/$', register, name='register'),
    url(r'^profile/$', profile, name='profile'),
    url(r'^profile/update/$', update_profile, name='update_profile'),
    url(r'^profile/kids/update/(?P<id>\d+)$', update_profile_kid, name='update_profile_kid'),
    url(r'^profile/kids/delete/(?P<id>\d+)$', delete_profile_kid, name='delete_profile_kid'),
    url(r'^profile/kids/create/$', create_profile_kid, name='create_profile_kid'),
    url(r'^logout/$', logout, name='logout'),
    url(r'^login', login, name='login'),
]
```

I am trying to debug the problem but I am so far unsuccessful. Can somebody help me or point me in the right direction.

Comment: If you're on a local environment (your development machine), you should set `DEBUG = True` in your settings.py file. That will show you the full error trace in the browser instead of just Error. Also regardless of the `DEBUG` setting, you should be able to see the detailed error in your console (where you did `manage.py runserver`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your views return just the string "Error" with no information in certain cases. That's what you see.

You should never `return HttpResponse("Error")` because that just returns a document with the text "Error" to the browser.

When your forms are not valid, you should just return the same page with the bound, invalid form and show the form errors to the user.

Read the [Forms documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/) and especially how to create a view that handles the three states of a form (unbound, bound invalid and bound valid) properly.

In general one view should handle it like this:

- If your `request.method` is `GET` you create the unbound, empty form (or with some `initial` values). You then return the template with this form so the user can fill it in.
- If your `request.method` is `POST` you create the bound form and check if it's valid.

  - If valid, you save and redirect.
  - If not valid, you also return the template with the bound form (same as the `GET` case). And now your template displays the form with the values that the user filled in previously and the errors so the user can correct them and try again.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this answer. I just noticed this  Error now. Thanks again.